# Focusing issues with my Nikon D3100 with some lenses

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting, nikon-d3100

My Nikon D3100 won't focus after a certain point, and there is a kind of low screechy noise when it tries to focus. Don't understand why it happens with my 55–200 and it doesn't happen with my 18–55 at all.

With the 55–200 lens it happens when the object is close. With my 70–300 lense I have to manually focus — it won't auto focus at all.

Comment: oh and it wont auto focus at all with my 70-300 lense.

Comment: Is this when the object is far away?

Comment: with the 55-200 lense it happens when things are close.. and my 70 -300 lense i have to manually focus that one ..it wont auto focus at all

Answer (score 3):

Nikkor 55-200 has minimum focus distance 1.1 meter ([found here](http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/246-nikkor-af-s-55-200mm-f4-56g-if-ed-dx-vr-review--test-report)). So if object is really close, it won't focus.

And if your Nikkor 70-300 is this one: [Nikkor AF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 D ED](http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/249-nikkor-af-70-300mm-f4-56-d-ed-review--test-report) (**do you?**), it won't focus at all on D3100. That lens doesn't have internal AF motor and D3100 also doesn't have focusing motor. With your D3100 you need lenses which have focusing motor, like [Nikkor AF-S 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6 G IF-ED VR](http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/250-nikkor-af-s-70-300mm-f45-56-g-if-ed-vr-review--test-report). Important is AF-S.

Comment: thank you sooo much for your help......oh man your right on the 70-300 ...what a ding i am ..i didnt even notice ..... as for the 55-200 ..it was focusing for awhile at that certain point and beyond but now it wont and it makes a screechy noise...hmmmm

Comment: It could also be that the 55-200 needs some TLC from a local service centre.  Screechy noises and lenses are rarely a good mix.

Comment: i just looked at my lens again the 70-300 it is a nikon AF nikkor 70-300mm ...doesnt that mean auto focus?!?!?

Comment: AF lenses use the cameras internal focus motor (if it has one). AF-S lenses have their own focus motor inside the lens.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I had a funny problem like this with my 18-55 and it turns out that it doesn't fit completely snugly on the camera mount and this causes bad contacts. If I twist the lens very lightly and seat it better in the mount the connection improves and the lens works again.